How to solve this maximization?
I'm facing this problem recently, how to optimize the problem?
$$\max_{\textbf{B}}\ \text{tr}\left(\textbf{A}\left(\textbf{B} \otimes\textbf{I}\right)\right)$$
$$\text{tr}(\textbf{B})\leq p$$
$\textbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{ab\times ab}$ is positive semi-definite and symmetric. $\textbf{B}\in\mathbb{C}^{b\times b}$, $\textbf{I}\in\mathbb{C}^{a\times a}$ is an identity matrix.
I don't know how  to deal the kronecker product. Is the function convex with $\textbf{B}$?

What do you mean by maximising a complex-valued function? Anyway, without imposing some further conditions on $B$ (such as requiring $B$ to be positive semidefinite), the real part and the absolute value of the trace are in general not bounded above.

and to complete, this is linear in $B$, so in particular it is convex, but not strictly convex

Sorry, $\textbf{B}$ is positive semidefinite, I forgot to mention it.

Partition $A$ into $b^2$ sub-blocks, each of size $a\times a$. Denote the $(i,j)$-th sub-block as $A^{(ij)}$. Then
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A(B\otimes I))
=\operatorname{tr}\sum_{i=1}^b\sum_{j=1}^bA^{(ij)}(B\otimes I)^{(ji)}
=\operatorname{tr}\sum_{i=1}^b\sum_{j=1}^bA^{(ij)}(b_{ji}I)
=\sum_{i=1}^b\sum_{j=1}^b\operatorname{tr}A^{(ij)}b_{ji}
=\operatorname{tr}(TB),
$$
where $T$ is the positive semidefinite $b\times b$ matrix given by $t_{ij}=\operatorname{tr}A^{(ij)}$. Therefore
$$
\max_{B\succeq0,\, \operatorname{tr}(B)\le p}\operatorname{tr}(TB)=p\lambda_\max(T)
$$
and $B=pvv^\ast$ is a global maximiser when $v$ is a unit eigenvector corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue of $T$.

$
\def\b{\beta}
\def\o{{\tt1}}   \def\mo{\,\big[\o\big]\,}
\def\e{\epsilon} \def\ee{\varepsilon}
\def\k{\otimes}  \def\c{\cdot}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\CR#1{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\op{sym}\LR{#1}}
\def\size#1{\op{size}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\rr#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=1}^a}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\fracBR#1#2{\BR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$The matrix variables have the following dimensions
$$\eqalign{
a,a &= \size{I_a}, \q
b,b &= \size{I_b} = \size{B}, \q
ab,ab &= \size{A} \\
}$$
Use $\ee_k$ to denote the $k^{th}$ column of $I_a$
$$\eqalign{
I_a &= \Sk \ee_k \ee_k^T \\
}$$
and a colon
to denote the trace product
$$\eqalign{
C:B &= \trace{C^TB} \\
B^*\!:B &= \frob{B}^2 \\
}$$
With this notation, we can isolate $B$ in the objective function
$$\eqalign{
\phi
 &= \trace{A\LR{B\k I_a}} \\
 &= A:\BR{B\k\LR{\Sk \ee_k \ee_k^T}} \\
 &= A:\Sk {\lR{I_b\c B\c I_b}\k\lR{\ee_k\c\mo\c\ee_k^T}} \\
 &= A:\Sk {\lR{I_b\k \ee_k}\c {B}\c\lR{I_b\k \ee_k^T}} \\
 &= \rr{\Sk \lR{I_b\k \ee_k^T}\c A\c\lR{I_b\k \ee_k}}:B \\
 &= \rr S:B \qq \lbrace{\sf note:}\;S=S^T\rbrace\\
}$$
Construct a psd $B$ matrix which satisfies the trace constraint
using an undetermined scalar $\LR{q\le p}$ and vector $\LR{u}$
$$\eqalign{
B = \fracBR{q}{u^*u}uu^* \qiq\trace{B} = q \:\le\: p \\
}$$
Then the objective becomes a Rayleigh Quotient
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= S:B \;=\; q\fracBR{u^*Su}{u^*u} \\
}$$
whose maximum corresponds to the maximal eigenpair $\LR{\lambda_{\max},u_{\max}}$ of the $S$ matrix.

I do not get where you use the constraint on the trace of $B$.

Many thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that $\textbf{B}$
is also p.s.d. If the condition is added, is the objective function bounded above?
